# undefined value in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I created a pie chart out of a html table with Highcharts. Everything works fine, the only problem is that whenever I hover a piece of my chart, it displays undefined. Below two screenshots of how my current solution looks like and what it should look like:
[what my solution looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4BZF.png)
[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caInn.png).

**Javascript code for highchart**:

```
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Auswertung Herkunftsbefragung'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(){
            return '<b>' +this.series.name + '</b><br />'+this.pointy+' '+this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**PHP Code which builds the HTML table**:

```
<table id="datatable" style="border: 1px solid black"><thead><tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Counter</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
foreach($analysis_data as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach(['country', 'counter'] as $attribute){
        echo "<td>".$row[$attribute]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

Does anybody know what I have to modify to archieve this?

Comment: just `this.pointy` is undefined use `this.point.y`

Comment: Just like in the com above and have you checked what the `this.series.name` returns in your case?

Comment: @Troopers: Well, such small mistakes always cost me a lot of time to search. Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Auswertung Herkunftsbefragung'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(){
            return '<b>' +this.series.name + '</b><br />'+this.point.y+' '+this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

`this.point.y` is undefined. Thanks to @Troopers